# Origin of "Why, hello there"

Tags: phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the use of “why” as an interjection come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/where-does-the-use-of-why-as-an-interjection-come-from)

This is a common English phrase that I'm sure everyone has heard before.

However, I find it puzzling that the phrase begins with "why" but isn't a question and doesn't end with a question mark.

If there is any story or explanation behind this, I would love to know.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197176/literature-why-at-the-beginning-of-sentences?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what we call a “General Reference” question around here.  It’s simply because *why* can be used as an interjection. Any good dictionary should have told you that. Here’s [what the *OED* says](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228829) about this sense of ***why***:

> 7. Used interjectionally, before a sentence or clause.
>
> - a. As an expression of surprise (sometimes only momentary or slight; sometimes involving protest), either in reply to a remark or question, or on perceiving something unexpected.
>
>   - ?1520   J. Rastell *Nature .iiii. Elem.* sig. Bvij,   Than I perceyue ye wyll make gode chere *Hu*. why what shulde I els do?
>   - 1581   *Confer. with Campion* (1583) C iij,   Why, is not Saint Iames Epistle called the Catholike Epistle of Saint Iames. How do you then denie it to be Canonicall?
>   - 1600   Shakespeare *Much Ado about Nothing* ɪᴠ. ii. 39   Why this is flat periurie, to call a Princes brother villaine.
>   - 1600   Shakespeare *Much Ado about Nothing* ᴠ. iv. 74   *Bene*. Do not you loue me? *Beat*. Why no, no more then reason.
>   - 1611   *Bible* (A.V.) Matt. xxvii. 23   They all sayde vnto him, Let him be crucified. And the Gouernour said, Why, what euil hath he done?
>   - 1712   R. Steele *Spectator* No. 533. ⁋1   What do I think? why, I think she cannot be above six foot two inches high.
>   - 1779   J. Warner in J. H. Jesse *G. Selwyn & his Contemp.* (1844) IV. 274   What was I to do in this more than Egyptian darkness? Why, go to bed. Very true.
>   - 1837   Dickens *Pickwick Papers* xxxviii. 417   ‘Goodness gracious!’ said Mary,‥ ‘Why it's that very house.’
>   - 1847   T. De Quincey *Secret Societies* in *Tait's Edinb. Mag.* Oct. 667/1   Were there no such people as the Essenes? Why, no; not as Josephus described them.
>   - 1863   C. Kingsley *Water-babies* iii. 103   And, as he spoke, he turned quite pale, and then quite white. ‘Why, you're ill!’ said Tom.
>   - 1893   M. Pemberton *Iron Pirate* i,   Mary looked up suddenly‥and said,‥‘Why, I believe I've been asleep!’
> - b. Emphasizing or calling more or less abrupt attention to the statement following (as in the apodosis of a sentence), in opposition to a possible or vaguely apprehended doubt or objection.
>
>   - 1545   T. Raynald tr. E. Roesslin *Byrth of Mankynde* 90   When she feleth greate ache in the inner parte of the eyes‥, yᵉ reste of the body taken as it were with a werynesse without any outwarde apparent cause: why these thynges portende‥aborcement to be at hande.
>   - 1590   T. Lodge *Rosalynde* (1592) N 2 b,   And to conceale it, why it doubled her griefe.
>   - 1594   *1st Pt. Contention* ɪɪ. i,   Why let me see, I thinke thou canst not see yet.
>   - *a*1596   *Sir T. More* (Malone Soc.) ɪ. i. 122   Take an honest woman from her husband! why, it is intollerable.
>   - 1604   Shakespeare *Hamlet* ɪ. ii. 121   *Ham*. I shall in all my best obay you Madam. *King*. Why tis a louing and a faire reply.
>   - 1604   Shakespeare *Hamlet* ɪɪɪ. ii. 259   Why let the strooken Deere goe weepe, The Hart vngauled play.
>   - *a*1616   Shakespeare *Two Gentlemen of Verona* ɪɪɪ (1623) ɪ. i. 33   If hap'ly won, perhaps a haplesse gaine, If lost, why then a grieuous labour won.
>   - 1647   A. Cowley *Request in Mistress* iii,   If her chill heart I cannot move, Why, I'le enjoy the very Love.
>   - 1719   Swift *Quiet Life* in *Wks*. (1735) II. 351   Why Dick, thy Wife has dev'lish whims.
>   - 1769   O. Goldsmith *Rom. Hist.* I. 439   If you will have Caesar for your master, why have him.
>   - 1841   Dickens *Old Curiosity Shop* ɪ. i. 42   ‘A long way, wasn't it, Kit?’‥ ‘Why then, it was a goodish stretch, master,’ returned Kit.
>   - 1863   C. Kingsley *Water-babies* iii. 103   If she chooses to come, why she  * may; and if not, why I go without her.
>   - 1869   G. J. Whyte-Melville *Songs & Verses* 93   So he made for the gate,‥And the chain being round it, why—over he flew!
>   - 1882   W. Besant *All Sorts of Men* II. xxiii. 139   ‘Not a doubt,’ added the Professor. ‘Why, it stands to reason.’
> - †c. As an emphasized call or summons, expressing some degree of impatience. *Obs.*
>
>   - 1599   Shakespeare *Romeo & Juliet* ɪᴠ. iv. 29   Mistris, what mistris, Iuliet‥Why Lambe, why Lady, fie you sluggabed, Why Loue I say‥why Bride.
>   - 1600   Shakespeare *Merchant of Venice* ɪɪ. v. 6   What Iessica.‥ Why Iessica I say.
>   - 1600   Shakespeare *Henry IV, Pt. 2* ᴠ. i. 6   What Dauy I say.‥ Why Dauy.
> - †d. ***why, so!*** an expression of content, acquiescence, or relief. *Obs*. or *arch*.
>
>   - 1597   Shakespeare *Richard II* ɪɪ. ii. 87   *Seruingman*. My Lord, your son was gone before I came. *Yorke*. He was; why so go all which way it will.
>   - *a*1616   Shakespeare Taming of Shrew (1623) iv. iii. 194   *Pet*.‥It shall be what a clock I say it is. *Hor*. Why so this gallant will command the sunne.
>   - *a*1616   Shakespeare *Macbeth* (1623) ɪɪɪ. iv. 106   Hence, horrible shadow.‥[*Ghost vanishes*.] Why, so, being gone, I am a man againe.
>   - 1826   Scott *Woodstock* I. iii. 65   If you will have the things rendered even now, why so—and if not, hold me blameless.

Comment: Sorry if this was an obvious question, I just wasn't sure what to search for.  I really appreciate your answer and examples.