# Use of seemingly wrong grammar in the poem(s)

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, word-usage

I read the poem 'A Roadside Stand' by Robert Frost, and I have accumulated a few questions through the poem. So, I will be posting some questions from the same poem, if you can, then please answer my other questions as well. Thanks to all :)

Have a look at the picture of the text I have added.
I have highlighted two things in the poem, which are concerned to this post.

First, the use of 'rest' instead of 'rested' seems wrong to me. Is poet's use of 'rest' really wrong grammatically? If it is not, then what difference it will make if 'rested' was used instead of 'rest'?

Second, the use of 'why keep their money' where I feel like 'why not keep their money' should be there. Is poet's sentence correct or incorrect grammatically in this case? If it is correct then what difference it will make if 'why not keep their money' was used?

I have seen this kind of grammar being used in several poems, is it a kind of a feature of poems in general?

(I'm not a native speaker, probably that's why I have these questions in my mind. I will be really happy if you could help me reach the answers to my questions.) Thanks again to all :)

[image]

Comment: What is the text? Please edit your question to add it in (as text, mind; not as an image), using bold to highlight the parts you’re having trouble with.

Comment: Extremely Sorry! I just forgot to add the text. Really sorry. It's added no :)

Comment: Of course the poet is not wrong! Analysing poetry and some literature is pointless, since both can violate the rules of grammar willy-nilly!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197176/literature-why-at-the-beginning-of-sentences

Comment: It is a general mistake to expect poetry to follow rules of grammar. That's not the way that poetry works.

Comment: Both words are perfectly normal and grammatical here. There is no poetic licence taken, really. _Rest_ is a noun here (your beauty rest is the same as your beauty sleep), and “why keep your money” just needs a comma for clarity: “Why, (I recommend that you just) keep your money and move on.”

Comment: Thanks @JanusBahsJacquet :) So, it comes down to the fact that Iam not a native english speaker. The thing you have pointed out in your comment is easily understood by me when I read a Hindi poem. Thanks for your explanation though! Also, can you elaborate how/in what sense 'rest' is a noun here?

Comment: @RohitShekhawat Beauty rest is one of the things that the signs offer for sale. The crude, homemade sign at a roadside stand (one of those little stands that sell fruits, vegetables, jams, eggs, etc.) displays several things as being for sale: wild berries, yellow squash (vegetables), or presumably vacant room to rent where you can get some beauty rest in the beautiful mountain scenery.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wonderful Explanation! Now I completely understand it, Thanks a loooot :D I would accept your explanations as the right answer if you could post your comments as an answer! ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**poetic licence** [oxford english](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poetic_licence)
noun

> The freedom to depart from the facts of a matter or from the
>   conventional rules of language when speaking or writing in order to
>   create an effect.
>       ‘he used a little poetic licence to embroider a good tale’

as @BillJ said poets exercise exceptions!

Comment: Thanks Ibf! I got what you want to say :) I was just wondering about the question, so I just posted it. Now, I have a lot of information, thanks to you people :)

Answer (score 1):

Poetry is a different animal from day-to-day prose, just as music is different from ordinary speech and industrial rumble. Frost, in particular, picked up the rhythms and odd characteristics of  regional English. Though not a native New Englander (born in San Francisco on the west coast), his family were from "back East" and he moved there soon enough. A reader who did not grow up in English might profit from hearing Frost's recordings of his poems (google on line for it) to hear how they SOUND, not just LOOK. Caveat: Not all poets read their work well, but Frost certainly did.

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to Frost's recording of this poem?

Comment: Thanks a lot Doctor Dee! I understood some important points from your answer. However, I couldn't find any recording of 'A Roadside Stand', and as Lawrence said, could you maybe provide a link for any recording you found. That will be great :D