# A question of gratitude?

Tags: reason-why

In this expression, (why thank you) there seems to be a question with a statement of gratitude. I have heard it all of my life growing up in Texas. I can even remember hearing it in the voice of Foghorn Leghorn "Why, I say why thank you."  Is it just southern colloquialism?  Another quote from Foghorn to end my question, 
“What’s it all about boy, elucidate!”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the 'why' is an interjection, rather than an interrogative.
A much longer answer has [already been provided](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/where-does-the-use-of-why-as-an-interjection-come-from)