# What does "why" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Have you ever thought of it Susie, and yet I know you have, how much
> these hearts claim; **why** I dont believe in the whole, wide world, are
> such hard little creditors - such real little misers, as you and I
> carry with us, in our bosoms every day. I cant help thinking
> sometimes, when I hear about the ungenerous, Heart, keep very still -
> or someone will find you out!

I found this in Emily Dickinson's letter.
Does "why" here mean the "reason" Emily doesn't believe the world?

Comment: If you're learning English, this material is not the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

In this context it is just an exclamation like "Well" or "hey". In this context it is not related to a reason.

Answer (score 1):

***Why*** is an interjection here and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/why) records this use as

> mainly US or old-fashioned: used to express surprise or anger:
>
> - ***Why***, I've never seen anything like it!

If you wish to know more about it, [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16762/where-does-the-use-of-why-as-an-interjection-come-from) will give you all the answers.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the history of its use like this or any indication of the semantic drift that might have lead here?